# If statements and AlertDialog boxes

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have this application which when you logged in, you will see a list of things like names. I have an Add, Update, and Delete button as well. When I hit the edit button, it will go to the edit page and and you can edit a name there. Now, when you hit the Update button, I have an AlertDialog which will ask for the user's username and password again. Here is the code I made:

```
public void btn_add_update_click(View v){
    hideKeyboard();
    final String username = getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME");
    final String str_sitename = this.edt_sitename.getText().toString();
    String str_username = this.edt_username.getText().toString();
    String str_password = this.edt_password.getText().toString();
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View prompt = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(prompt);
    final EditText user = (EditText) prompt.findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    final EditText pass = (EditText) prompt.findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);
    final TextView msg = (TextView) prompt.findViewById(R.id.login_error);
    final String password = pass.getText().toString();
    user.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("USERNAME"));


    if (str_sitename.equals("")){
        //edt_sitename.requestFocus();
        show_mesg("Please insert sitename.");
    }else if (str_username.equals("")){
        //edt_username.requestFocus();
        show_mesg("Please insert username.");
    }else if (str_password.equals("")){
        //edt_password.requestFocus();
        show_mesg("Please insert password.");
    }else{
        if (selected_website!=null){
            selected_website.setUser(username);
            selected_website.setSitename(str_sitename);
            selected_website.setUsername(str_username);
            selected_website.setPassword(str_password);
                alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {    
                        DBAdapter dbUser = new DBAdapter(PasswordActivity.this);
                        dbUser.open();
                        if(dbUser.Login(username, password))
                        {
                                datasource.updateWebsite(selected_website);
                                show_mesg(str_sitename + " updated.");
                                hideKeyboard();
                                selected_website = null;
                                show_list_layout(); 
                            }
                        else{
                            msg.setText("Username or Password is not correct.");
                            }
                        }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show(); 
        }

        else{
            datasource.addWebsite(username, str_sitename,str_username,str_password);
            hideKeyboard();
            show_mesg(str_sitename + " added.");
            selected_website = null;
            show_add_layout();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run it, it doesn't work. The OK and the Cancel button is not showing up.
Any advice on this?

Answer (score 1):

First thing is are you sure your control is coming to the update condition? If so, it doesn't seem any flaw in your code while creating alert dialog. Anyways it's worth to try this,if you are sure your control is in update condition.

```
 void showUpdateDialog(){
      AlertDialog.Builder updateDialog  = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourClassName.this);
      updateDialog.setTitle("Update Dialog");
      updateDialog.setCancelable(false);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater  = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

  View inflatingView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.updatelayout,null);

      EditText user = (EditText) inflatingView.findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
      EditText pass = (EditText) inflatingView.findViewById(R.id.loginPassword);

      // More views here.......

 updateDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }});

  updateDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   }});

        updateDialog.setView(inflatingView);
        updateDialog.show();
    }
```

Call this `showUpdateDialog()` method when the update button is clicked in your activity. If you still don't find your positive and negative buttons, create your own buttons. Then you don't need to depend on the system's positive and negative buttons. Add two extra buttons in your updatelayout.xml and code it like below in your showUpdateDialog() method and do whatever you want with those buttons.

```
Button yesButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.positiveButton);
  yesButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Yes Button Is Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }});
```

Comment: i have added your code. But still, the OK and the Cancel buttons are not showing up? It only shows my EditTexts.

Comment: EditTexts?? Where these edittexts come from? Alert dialog is shown with out yes and no buttons or it is completely not shown?  Okay. Add some log.d in update button click. See whether control is flowing in that condition and let me know.

Comment: final EditText user = (EditText) prompt.findViewById(R.id.loginEmail);
    final EditText pass = (EditText) prompt.findViewById(R.id.loginPassword); these are my edittexts

Comment: i added some toast to it, and still not working. The OK and the CANCEL buttons are not showing up. It seems that they are hidden or something

Comment: Yes your custom layout might be hiding it. Will edit my answer and check with it.

Comment: alright. well if you want to, i can send u the whole project so you can see what is particularly wrong.